# Why 3 font-size declaration

Tags: css

I've downloaded a standard theme whose main file normalize.css contains these declarations in the very beginning. **I'm confused why three font-sizes**:

```
html {
  font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, "DejaVu Sans", sans-serif; /* 1 */

  /* Delete all but one of the following font-size declarations: */

  /* Use a 12px base font size. 16px x 75% = 12px */
  font-size: 75%; /* 3 */
  /* Use a 14px base font size. 16px x .875 = 14px */
  font-size: 87.5%; /* 3 */
  /* Use a 16px base font size. */
  font-size: 100%; /* 3 */

  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;     /* 2 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */

  /* Establish a vertical rhythm. */
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

All I want is to use base font-size of 14px.

Comment: It´s **probably** only info for you, what percentage you has to use for font size XXpx. Set there only one, the rest you can remove.

Comment: as stated by `/* Delete all but one of the following font-size declarations: */` leave just one declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments, you should leave the `font-size: 87.5%;` deceleration and delete the other two `font-size` decelerations.